# how to store the first value of variable in a C# function (in a loop)

Tags: c#

I have a function (in a loop) will plot real-time temperature (Series["Experiment"]), and also I have a theoretic data (Series["Theory"]) want to be plotted on the same figure. However, theory plot must have the same start time with the experiment, so I have to define the ***initial_time***, it should be the value of(date.Hour * 3600 + date.Minute * 60 + date.Second) in the first loop, and be fixed in the program.  How to extract this initial_time? if it is in a C program, I will use a static int initial_time=date.Hour * 3600 + date.Minute * 60 + date.Second, but this is a C# and I could not define static in in a function....

```
private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            var date = DateTime.Now;
            x = date.Hour * 3600 + date.Minute * 60 + date.Second;
            this.chart1.Series["Experiment"].Points.AddXY(x, myFloat);
            int[] theory_x = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
            int[] theory_y = new int[] { 100, 200, 250, 300, 400};
            int theory_x_new=theory_x+***initial_time***;
            this.chart1.Series["Theory"].Points.AddXY(theory_x_new, theory_y);

        }
catch (Exception)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `[...] and be fixed in the program` ? Is this `WPF` or `WindowsForms` ?

Answer (score 2):

Make a `bool` outside the function, probably some class level variable.

```
    private boolean loaded = false;
    private int initial_time = 0;
```

Then in you loop function:

```
    if(!loaded){
       loaded = true;

       var date = DateTime.Now;
       initial_time = date.Hour * 3600 + date.Minute * 60 + date.Second;
    }
```

**Update**:
As ColinWilliams says in his comments `initial_time` would also need to be a class level variable.

Comment: I could have misunderstood the OP's question, but I think they would need to save the calculated date. Same principle applies, but a class-level variable for the date would need to be used as well.

Comment: @ColinWilliams probably `initial_time` is a variable at class level

Comment: Ah ok, I think it would be good to clarify that in your answer as it's unclear in the question. Otherwise completely agree with your answer.

Comment: @ColinWilliams agreed! update the answer. I think Motivated's answer is quite elegant I don't know how I missed that way!

Comment: thanks for all people helped, I begin to find C# is more and more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Well since you only want to set it the first time you run through the loop I guess this will do it:

```
//Somewhere out of your fuction:
private int initial_time; // = 0 (default)


if(initial_time == 0) //No value is set (0 is default for int)
{
    initial_time = DateTime.Now.Hour * 3600 + DateTime.Now.Minute * 60 + DateTime.Now.Second;
}
```

So in the 2nd iteration it is not set again. 
This means the value is "constant" as long as your class is in scope.

Comment: thank you very much! It works! This one is simple and beautiful!

Comment: @adamwu NOTE: since you only use `Hour,Minute,Seconds` when your program runs longer than `12 h / 24 h` you cannot tell when it started ...